# Saving a image from a remote server to disk

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is this possible in Angularjs? Googling has returned not many results, mostly for php and express. The reason why I want to do it client side is because I've already have the url in place, so i might as well do it there. Unless my approach is completely wrong, please enlighten me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cant be done directly using Angular. We followed the below steps to achieve downloading of image.

1. Instead of accessing the image through URL directly, have a PHP page which serves the image by accepting image name.
2. Add download header to the PHP so that it will open save dialogue if you access the URL.

> ```
> header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
> header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
> header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
> header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
> header('Expires: 0');
> header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
> header('Pragma: public');
> header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
> ```

eg.,

```
<a href="imageprovider.php?imgeurl" target"_blank">download</a>
```

will download the image.